# Export chart to png (Chart.js)

Tags: chart.js

Is there anyway to export the chart to a image without the need to create a canvas and all. This is what I am trying to do, first I want to create a chart with all the necessary data and then I want to export that to png all in the server side, without touching html.

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js is a canvas based library so you always need some sort of canvas, either a normal one, an offscreen one or an equivalant in node. If you dont want to create your own canvas you can use [quickChart](https://quickchart.io/). Here you can pass your config and you get a png with that chart back